# Why does VerificationController crash inside of didReceiveData

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, automatic-ref-counting

Here is the function where it crashes.  The exact line of code is the one with: removeObjectForKey.  Even when the test function is completely empty it crashes on removeObjectForKey.  Note: I'm just passing in an empty function callback.  currently, I have ARC off,  do i need to turn it on?  If possible, i would like to do it with ARC off, because turning it on would mean dealing with alot of compile issues.

the function does say something about non-retained objects, hence could be a memory issue.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // So we got some receipt data. Now does it all check out?
    BOOL isOk = [self doesTransactionInfoMatchReceipt:responseString];

    VerifyCompletionHandler completionHandler = _completionHandlers[[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:connection]];
    [_completionHandlers removeObjectForKey:[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:connection]];

    if (isOk)
    {
        //Validation suceeded. Unlock content here.
        NSLog(@"Validation successful");
        completionHandler(TRUE);

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Validation failed");
        completionHandler(FALSE);
    }
}
```

Here is the verificationController usage:

```
    [[VerificationController sharedInstance] verifyPurchase:transaction completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        if (success) {

            NSLog(@"Hi, its success.");
            [self testMethod];

       } else {
            NSLog(@"payment not authorized.");
        }
    }];         
}

- (void) testMethod {

}
```

I could use __weak but then I would have to turn on ARC, which i'm trying to avoid.  Note: the verificaitionController works when I put it inside other Classes/Objects, but as soon as I put it in the InAppPurchaseManager it blows up anytime it tries to access self.  Self points to an instance of InAppPurchaseManager as defined like so (its a phonegap plugin):

```
@interface InAppPurchaseManager : CDVPlugin <SKPaymentTransactionObserver> {

}
```

Comment: what does the error log show?

Comment: nothing in the error log.

Answer (score 3):

I also ran into this problem i fixed this issue this way
main issue is when you are setting value to completion handler in verifyPurchase method it is setting nil value so find this line in verifyPurchase method

```
  _completionHandlers[[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:conn]] = completionHandler;
```

and replace it with

```
 [_completionHandlers setObject:[completionHandler copy] forKey:[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:conn]];
```

and find the connectionDidReceivedata method and replace it with

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // So we got some receipt data. Now does it all check out?
    BOOL isOk = [self doesTransactionInfoMatchReceipt:responseString];


    if (_completionHandlers && [_completionHandlers respondsToSelector:@selector(removeObjectForKey:)])
    {
        VerifyCompletionHandler completionHandler = _completionHandlers[[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:connection]];
        [_completionHandlers removeObjectForKey:[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:connection]];
        if (isOk)
        {
            //Validation suceeded. Unlock content here.
            NSLog(@"Validation successful");
            completionHandler(TRUE);

        } else {
            NSLog(@"Validation failed");
            completionHandler(FALSE);
        }

    }
    //[_completionHandlers removeObjectForKey:[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:connection]];
   }
```

Hope this may help you and saves alot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Is _completionHandlers nil?  You might do something like this -

```
if (_completionHandlers && [_completionHandlers respondsToSelector:@selector(removeObjectForKey:)]) {
    [_completionHandlers removeObjectForKey:[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:connection]];
}
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Find following string:

```
[_completionHandlers setObject:completionHandler forKey:[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:conn]];
```

And change to:

```
[_completionHandlers setObject:[completionHandler copy] forKey:[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:conn]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you found the answer yet, but I just realized that _completionHandlers is never allocated (and if you po _completionHandlers after setting a breakpoint you will notice it is nil). Hope this helps!

```
// in VerificationController.m

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        transactionsReceiptStorageDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        _completionHandlers = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    }
    return self;
}
```